# Make Calibre to ask for an application each time

Tags: calibre

I have a huge ebook library of pdf files very big ones and small ones too. I use **MuPDF** as default application to read PDF files but some files are best viewed in **Document Viewer**. I need a way so that every time when I click on a PDF file to ask for an application to open it by default.

Note: I use Calibre to manage my library, so "Right-click → Properties → Open With" is not available.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what is your problem, when you do **right-click** and **open with** option! What would be better than that!

Comment: I use calibre as my library manager so i browse my books through calibre and these is no such facility as nautilus right-click.

Comment: It should... Right-click > Properties > Open With...?

Comment: Please don't edit if you are not sure what you are doing calibre only send the signal to open the file it is ubuntu who decide which application to use. @SauravKumar

Comment: @drofart: Yes as your wish. I edited according to my understanding.  But you can add `calibre` as tags. right?

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround might be that you first open the path to folder ("Path: Click to open" in the righthand pane with the book details). The file manager opens the folder with the containing file and you can right-click and choose your application from there.
It does take a couple of more clicks, though.

There is a plugin "open with" (see [here](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=118761)) you could use. Set it to open pdf files with MuPDF, and when you want to open a pdf file with Document Viewer use the method above.
You might also create a custom column that tells you which pdf files are best opened with Document Viewer.